# JavaBean set attributes. Multiple if-statements alternative

Tags: java, refactoring, javabeans

Again I would like to get your opinion about a design issue.

I have a JavaBean with 15 attributes. For feeding the attributes I have a **for loop** that iterates over a collection of key-value pairs (concretely SAML attributes, I am mapping the attributes response to principals attributes). I am invoking the appropriate *setter* method basis on the key value, this is:

```
    .../...
    for (SAML2AttributeInfo attr : attrs) {
        if (attr.getAttributeName().equals("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/upn")) {
            customPrincipal.setUpn(attr.getAttributeValues().iterator().next());
        }
        .../... so on and so forth
    }
```

It works, ok, but I have an ugly piece of code, 15 if-statements like above do not look very elegant.

I am thinking on using [Reflection](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/Reflection/), this is, develop a unique *set* method and pass it the name of the attribute and his value.

Another option could be store the attributes in a [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html), but I am not sure...

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance,

Luis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Polymorphism for the rescue**

```
enum Attribute {
    UPN("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/upn") {
        void setValue(Principal principal, String value) {
            principal.setUpn(value);
        }
    },
    ...
    ;

    private final String name;

    private Attribute(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public abstract setValue(Principal principal, String name);

    public static Attribute getByName(String name) {
        for (Attribute attribute : values())
            if (attribute.name.equals(name))
                return attribute;

        return null;
    }

    public static void setByName(Principal principal, String name, String value) {
        Attribute attribute = getByName(name);

        if (attribute == null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("No such attribute");

        attribute.setValue(principal, value);
    }
}
```

If you know the attribute you want to set there is no reason to go go via the name:

```
Attribute.UPN.setValue(principal, "something");
```

Comment: I would go further and add a static Attribute getByName(String name) method in the enum, to avoid forcing the client to iterate over all the values.

Comment: Hi JB Nizet, thank you very much. I have implemented a method like this: `public static Attribute getAttributeByName(String name) {
  Attribute attribute = null;
  for (Attribute attr : Attribute.values()) {
   if(attr.getName().equals(name))
    attribute = attr;
   break;
  } 
  return attribute;
 }` I am not sure wether is the best implementation...

Answer (score 2):

I would use a Map and declare static variables with the attribute keys:

```
public class Bean {
  public static final String ATTRIBUTE_1 = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/upn";
  public static final String ATTRIBUTE_2 = "...";
  ...
  public static final String ATTRIBUTE_N = "...";


  private Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();

  public void put(String key, Object value) {
    map.put(key, value);
  }

  public Object get(String key) {
    map.get(key);
  }
}
```

Then, you coud store / retrieve values using the static variables:

```
Bean bean = new Bean();

bean.set(Bean.ATTRIBUTE_1, someValue);

Object value = bean.get(Bean.ATTRIBUTE_1);
```

Comment: A list of constants like that should be replaced by an enum.

Comment: Thank you very much Pablo. This was also my first approach.